# contar fechas de una semana sql server

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

buen día lo que quiero es hacer una consulta  que me diga  la semana pasada  tiene ejemplo 15 solicitudes empezando del lunes a viernes y a lado o abajo ejemplo 10 solicitudes de la semana antepasada así sucesivamente pero todo en una sola consulta. espero me puedan ayudar, espero también ser especifico en lo que que quiero. gracias! este mi codigo, dateadd es para que tome la fecha de hoy  y valla hacia la semana pasada

```
select  count (t1.ID_SolicitudContrato) as conteo,
        t1.fecha_Actualizacion,
        t1.alcanceContrato,
         t2.ID_SolicitudContrato,
        t2.fecha_Actualizacion,
        t2.alcanceContrato  
        from CON_SolicitudContrato as t1
        inner join  CON_SolicitudContrato as t2 on t1.fecha_Actualizacion =t2.fecha_Actualizacion
        where t1.fecha_Actualizacion<DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),5)
        and  t1.fecha_Actualizacion >DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),0)
        and t2.fecha_Actualizacion<DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,14,GETDATE()),5)
        and  t2.fecha_Actualizacion >DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,14,GETDATE()),0)
        group by t1.ID_SolicitudContrato  ,t1.fecha_Actualizacion,t1.alcanceContrato,t2.ID_SolicitudContrato  ,t2.fecha_Actualizacion,t2.alcanceContrato
        order by t1.ID_SolicitudContrato desc
```

Comment: La verdad es que no es muy específico. Tendrías que escribir cuál es la estructura de las tablas involucradas, un ejemplo de datos que tenga esa tabla y un ejemplo del resultado esperado

Comment: ya edite mi publicacion para ver si me doy a enteder

Comment: Se necesitan saber cuales son las tablas, los datos esperados, los datos que tenes y que sale actualmente. Ademas del query, y saber que motor de base de datos estas usando, esto ultimo debe ir en la etiqueta de la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Como primer punto sabemos que el año tiene 52 semanas

https://espanol.epochconverter.com/semanas/2018

como segundo punto la función que usaremos para saber en que numero de semana se encuentra la fecha es DATEPART

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

sabiendo estos datos y lo que entendí en tu pregunta es que quieres saber la cantidad de solicitudes ingresadas por semana.

aqui te dejo un ejemplo de como seria :

```
DECLARE @TABLE AS TABLE(
Id int identity(1,1),
solicitud int,
fecha datetime
)

declare @i as int = 1;

while (@i <= 31 )
begin
    insert into @TABLE (solicitud,fecha) values (@i,dateadd(day,@i,getdate()))
    set @i = @i + 1
end


--select  DATEPART(week,fecha),* from @TABLE
select  DATEPART(week,fecha) 'Numero de semana' ,count(id) 'cantidad de solicitud ',year(fecha) year from @TABLE group by DATEPART(week,fecha),year(fecha) order by year(fecha) asc
```

[image: resultado]